# LINQ-to-Entities with 8-bit ASCII data

Tags: linq, entity-framework, utf-8, codepages, non-ascii-characters

I have an interesting issue handling 8-bit "ASCII" characters in LINQ-to-Entities and am hoping someone can give me a tip.

I have inherited a SQL Server 2000 database that has some pseudo-encrypted columns where they just XOR'd the string with `0xFF`. Don't know why and I know it's lame but that's where we are now.

These columns are of SQL datatype `char(7)` and `char(14)`. When you XOR using `0xFF` you get the 8th bit set in every case, so you end up with non-ASCII (by Microsoft's definition anyway) characters. UTF-8 seems to be indicated here but the decoding gets messed up.

I am able to read and decode these strings as follows:

1. Get the field using LINQ as a `String`.
2. Get a `byte[]` using `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes()`
3. Decode by XORing each byte with `0xFF`
4. Return the decoded string with `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString()`

This works perfectly.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to put an ENCODED string back to SQL Server using LINQ.

I am basically following the reverse process and am doing:

1. Get the bytes using `ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes()`. (No need for CodePage 1252 here as this is a straight string.)
2. Encode the bytes with `0xFF`.
3. Return the encoded string with `GetEncoding(1252).GetString()`.

If I look at my string, it's exactly what I'd expect. But if I stuff that in my entity and do a `SaveChanges()` the resultant value in SQL Server is always `"?????"` of some length.

I'm sure I'm missing something here but I've tried everything I can think of and can't get it. For now I just fell back to the old-fashioned way of using a `SqlCommand` and doing an UPDATE with the encoded strings as `SqlParameters`.  No problem there, works every time.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

---

Update:

I tried the suggestion from JamieSee and I'm not even getting good decoding with his method.  I have:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Encoding characterEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);

        HCBPWEBEntities ent = new HCBPWEBEntities();

        var encUser =
            (from users in ent.tblEmployer
            where users.ipkEmpId == 357
            select users.sKey).First();

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Original XOR Encoded PW: {0}", encUser.ToString().Trim());

        byte[] originalBytes = (from character in characterEncoding.GetBytes(encUser.ToString().Trim())
                               select (byte)(character)).ToArray();

        Console.Write("Original Bytes:\t");
        foreach (byte b in originalBytes)
        {
            Console.Write("{0:x} ", b);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);

        byte[] decodedBytes = (from character in characterEncoding.GetBytes(encUser.ToString().Trim())
                               select (byte)(character ^ 0xFF)).ToArray();

        Console.Write("Decoded Bytes:\t");
        foreach (byte b in decodedBytes)
        {
            Console.Write("{0:x} ", b);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);

        string decoded = characterEncoding.GetString(decodedBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded PW: {0}", decoded);

        ent.Dispose();
    }
```

But the result of that are:

Original XOR Encoded PW: z?o>
Original Bytes: 7a 9d 6f 3e
Decoded Bytes:  85 62 90 c1
Decoded PW: ?b?A

The password is actually "abcd"

Comment: Please capture the SQL executed by L2S using SQL Profiler and post it. (It is extremely easy to do that.)

Comment: I'm using LINQ-to-Entities and not LINQ-to-SQL but capturing the SQL using Profiler is a good idea.  I'll set that up and see what it says.  But my guess is that it will show that SQL is storing exactly what it's being told to store.  I really believe the issue is in mapping the non-ASCII chars from Entity FW to SQL.

Comment: What's your collation for the database in question? You can find it with `SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'mydatabase'`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use code page 1252 use `Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)` (iso-8859-1) or `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)` (ibm850), either of which gives you 8-bit ASCII-based character sets.

Here's some quick & dirty code, which you can try with different encodings, to demonstrate your issue and the solution:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Encoding characterEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);

    string original = "This is some bogus data to test the problem.";
    Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", original);

    Console.Write("Original Bytes: ");
    foreach (byte b in characterEncoding.GetBytes(original))
    {
        Console.Write("{0:x}", b);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    byte[] encodedBytes = (from character in characterEncoding.GetBytes(original)
                           select (byte)(character ^ 0xFF)).ToArray();

    Console.Write("Encoded Bytes: ");
    foreach (byte b in encodedBytes)
    {
        Console.Write("{0:x}", b);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    string encoded = characterEncoding.GetString(encodedBytes);

    byte[] decodedBytes = (from character in characterEncoding.GetBytes(encoded)
                           select (byte)(character ^ 0xFF)).ToArray();

    Console.Write("Decoded Bytes: ");
    foreach (byte b in decodedBytes)
    {
        Console.Write("{0:x}", b);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    string decoded = characterEncoding.GetString(decodedBytes);

    Console.WriteLine("Decoded String: {0}", decoded);
}
```